# How can I expand a terminal using the command line?

Tags: command-line, terminal, window

When I start the terminal in my xfce Destop environment a black winodw about a quarter of the screen size appears, if I want to expand it to full screen size I have to click on the "+"-shaped symbol in its upper right corner. Is it possible to do the same without clicking onto it, just by using the command line ? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you find the fact that the window starts so small annoying, and do not actually want to *programatically* change the window size.

The shortcut to maximize any window is `alt+F5`. If that is too inconvenient you can change it via the system settings, or just drag the window up against the top edge of the screen, after making sure you have that activated in `settings -> window manager tweaks -> accessibility -> automatically tile windows when moving to screen edge`

You can also change the default size of the terminal, which for `xfce4-terminal` is done by selecting

```
edit -> preferences -> "appearance" tab -> Default geometry
```

This will not maximize your window by default though, just set it to the given size, so you might prefer the above solutions.